# How to upload an image using jQuery / AJAX in an ASP.NET MVC website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, file-upload, image-uploading

I'm trying to find a decent way of allowing users to upload a profile photo on an edit profile page.

I've tried out [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) but this doesn't appear to work under some of the more recent Google Chrome browser releases.

Ideally, I just want to offer the user the ability to replace a placeholder profile image with an image of their own, via a simple upload button (preferably ajax), and once an image has been upload, to show a 'delete' button to remove the uploaded photo and re-instate the default placeholder image.

Are there any other alternatives that play nicely across all the main browsers and integrate easily into an MVC application?

Answer (score 0):

To upload with jQuery only with HTML 5, and not all browser are able to this.

You can do something like this.

You need to have a IFRAME that  'll be use to make the post with the file.

Like this:

```
<iframe id="targetUpload" name="targetUpload"></iframe>
```

In the form you set the target to the iframe.

```
<form target="targetUpload" name="file" runat="server" method="post" id="file" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="@Url.Content("~/Controller/Upload")">
```

And a submit button

```
<input type="Submit" value="Upload">
```

This is a way to upload files without refresh the page.

You can treat the files before upload with jquery. (File type, size, etc...)

And in yout controller you recive the files:

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                //Save the file in the server path
                string savePath = Server.MapPath("~/Upload/");
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                savePath += fileName;
                file.SaveAs(savePath);
            }
          return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```